# I need help module in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

this is script of "tabs"module I want to change to select box with options

I tried to change the code but I could not this original code:

can someone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load',function(){
var spTab<?php echo $uniqid ?> = new sptabs($('sptab<?php echo $uniqid ?>'), {
    animation : <?php echo "'" . $animation . "'" ?>,
    btnPos: <?php echo "'" . $btnPos . "'" ?>,
    activator: <?php echo "'" . $activator . "'" ?>,
    transition: <?php echo 'Fx.Transitions.' . $transition ?>,
    fxduration: <?php echo $fxspeed ?>,
    autoHeight : <?php echo $body_height ?>,
    fixedHeight: <?php echo $fixed_height ?>
    });
});
</script>
<div class="<?php echo $color ?>" id="sptab<?php echo $uniqid ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
    <div style="display:none">
        <div class="tab-padding">
            <h2 style="display:none" class="title"><span id="<?php echo (preg_replace('/\s+/', '_',strtolower($item['title']))); ?>" class="sptab-title<?php echo ($item['sfx']) ? ' sptab_sfx' . $item['sfx'] : ''; ?>"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></span></h2>
            <?php echo $item['content']; ?>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need the javascript then, if you change the code to select? DO you need it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
     <option><?php echo $item['title']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</select>
```

Note that you **won't** need the javascript you provided in your question

Comment: so witch javescript I need?

Comment: I already said in my answer >> `Note that you won't need the javascript you provided in your question`

Comment: I understand it. but I want that when I click on item in select box it's will load module